# Find functions $f(m,n)$ to make $a_m\times a_n= f(m,n)a_{m+n}$ associative

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, homology-cohomology, group-cohomology, associativity

Let $A$ be a free Abelian monoid generated by the elements $\{a_n| n\in\mathbb{Z},n\geq 0\}$, i.e. a generic element of $A$ is a formal (finite) linear combination of $\{a_n| n\in\mathbb{Z},n\geq 0\}$ with non-negative integer coefficients, e.g. $2a_1+5a_4+3a_5$. Define a multiplication "$\times$" on $A$ as
$$a_m\times a_n=f(m,n)a_{m+n},$$
where $f(m,n)$ are non-negative integer coefficients. I want to find all such functions $f(m,n)$ such that "$\times$" is commutative, unital (with multiplicative unit $a_0$), and associative, i.e. $f(m,n)$ satisfies:

(1). $f(m,n)=f(n,m), \forall m,n\geq 0$;

(2). $f(0,n)=1,\forall n\geq 0$;

(3). $f(m,n)f(m+n,p)=f(n,p)f(m,n+p),\forall m,n,p\geq 0$.

Apparently, $f(m,n)\equiv 1$ trivially satisfies all above. My question is, **are there any solutions beyond this trivial one?**

Note that I could have let $A$ to be a free Abelian  group (or even a vector space over a field $F$) generated by the same elements and allow $f(m,n)$ to take integer values (or values in $F$ for the case of $A$ being a vector space), and then I can ask the same question. But let's solve the monoid case first.

Comment: The answer is more well-known if we consider a group $G$ instead of a monoid and talk about modifying the multiplication on $R[G]$ where $R$ is a commutative ring. The answer there is that the coefficients $c(g, h)$ have to form what is called a $2$-cocycle with coefficients in $R^{\times}$, and these can be classified up to a natural equivalence relation using group cohomology. I think in the monoid case we get something similar but maybe a little weirder.